# How to let 'kill' ignore processes that are not alive

Tags: linux, kill

How to tell the `kill` command to ignore processes if that process is not alive?

For example: `3453` is an alive process but `44534` is not.

```
kill -9 3453 44534
```

Comment: Also, what you're asking is not quite clear. Could you rephrase or elaborate to say exactly what you want to happen?

Answer (score 4):

```
for pid in 3453 44534
do
  kill -9 "$pid" > /dev/null 2> /dev/null || :
done
```

See [*Bash Reference Documentation: Job Control Builtins. `kill`*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#index-kill)

Comment: Or [test -d /proc/$pid && kill -9 $pid`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043978/how-to-check-if-a-process-id-pid-exists#comment113189911_15774758)

Comment: What's the purpose with the pipes and colon at the end of the main line?

Comment: @d-b : Regarding "*What's the purpose with the pipes and colon at the end of the main line?*": my assumption for @ignacio-vazquez-abrams adding `... || :` to the end: Imagine a script set up with the common practice of `set -euo pipefail`. Such script [immediately exits if a pipeline returns a non-zero status](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#index-set). If the process identified by`$pid` does not exist (anymore), then [`kill -9 "$pid"` will return a non-zero status](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#index-kill).

Comment: ... in such a non-zero `kill` exit status case, the [*OR operator* (`||`, "*the pipes*")](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html) makes sure to "swallow" the non-zero exit code and will have bash execute the command following `||`. This next command happens to be `:`. This ["*colon operator*" is a shell builtin command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-_003a) that does nothing besides always returning a status of zero....

Comment: Therefore, no matter the success/exit status of killing an existing or non-existing process, if the *for loop* tries killing a non-existing process, the loop will always continue looping over all remaining specified `$pid`s. If there wasn't the `[...] || :`, and the whole script was set up with `set -e`, the loop construct and the whole script would exit (too early) without killing the remaining `$pid`s.

Answer (score 2):

```
kill -9 3453 || kill -9 44535
```

Comment: And what if the situation were reversed? Or if both are alive?

Answer (score 0):

```
taskid=12345

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $taskid > /dev/null; then
  kill -9 $taskid
  # Task killed
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Most people are not aware that `kill` is a built-in command for many shells and I am assuming that you are using bash and that you would like to suppress the "no such process" messages that may be generated.  The executable located in `/bin/kill` on one of my machines generates no such messages.

```
$ /bin/kill -9 3453 44534
```

Comment: and it also generates error...